# Enabling collection unhides all objects

Tags: collections, layers

Whenever I enable a collection in Blender, it unhides all objects that I've selectively hidden. This is very irritating as it means I needs to rehide the objects I want hidden, or keep objects in separate collections.

Comment: unfortunately that's how it works right now

Comment: I've noticed that and I made a request in the Right Click Select site ( https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/XSgbbc/ ), but if you do it through the Extrude From Layer option it works the way you want, it keeps hidding the collections that are hidden, but you may want to use the Hide In Viewport option for some reason

Comment: Does my Blender 2.92 work differently or is there a misunderstanding on my behalf? I've got two collections. Both of them have visible and hidden objects. If I disable one collection, all objects disappear. If I enable it again, only the before visible objects reappear, the hidden objects stay hidden.

Comment: You are supposed to use the "monitor icon" visibility setting instead of the "eye icon" one in order to ensure objects stay hidden. If you hover over the eye icon it says "Temporarily hide in Viewport".

Comment: Oh I see, you're right... the "eye" icon gets enabled with the collection. Didn't realize that because almost always I only use "monitor" or "camera" icons since the benefit of the "eye" wasn't clear to me. The "monitor" helps me keep things invisible while I don't wish to see them - but not accidentally render the image without them. And the "camera" is useful if I explicitly want to render without certain objects for test renders etc. I know _Hide (H)_ and _Unhide (Alt+H)_ uses this "eye" icon, but since I use those shortcuts almost exclusively in _Edit Mode_ that's not important either.

Answer (score 4):

The eye icon hides objects temporarily. To hide objects globally, use the screen icon.
You can enable it from the outliner "funnel" menu.

**Temporarily Hide objects** (Eye icon[image])
Resets when a collection is enabled, duplicated or linked to another scene

**Globally disable objects** (Screen icon [image] )
Stays on when collection is enabled, duplicated or linked

[image]