# Toggle visiblity across instances

Tags: instances

I have created a collection with one object in it. Then I added multiple collection instances of that collection to my scene. I would like to easily toggle the visibility of the object across all instances. Is this possible? When I toggle the visibility of the object in the "original" collection, it does not affect the visibility of the instanced objects.

I want to do this in the viewport, not the final render.

Comment: Hi :). You can do this by using the "screen" icon instead of the "eye" icon. Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/220270/78972

Comment: @jachymmichal Thank you!!!!!